Is it possible to get the index of the highlighted selection of a popup_menu before confirming?
Typically, in a popup_menu you select a line and once you confirm it a callback function that takes popup window ID and index of the selection is invoked.
I am wondering if it is possible to get the index of the selection before confirming.
For example, if my popup_menu is showing the following:
   banana
   apple
   oranges

and my selection is on apple, is there a way to take its index ( = 2) before hitting <enter> or <space>?

Popup menu here is popup window where current item index equals cursor position line number.
You can query it using :h getcurpos() function with winid of your popup window:
vim9script

var my_fruit = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
var my_animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'snake']

def MyPopupCallback(type: string, id: number, idx: number)
   # Here I want to do something depending if 'type' arg passed to MyPopup() is 'animals' or 'fruit'
   echow type idx
enddef

def MyPopup(title: string, results: list<string>, type: string): number
  var winid = popup_menu(results, {
    title: title,
    callback: (id, idx) => {
        MyPopupCallback(type, id, idx)
    },
  })
  return winid
enddef

var winid = MyPopup('My food', my_fruit, 'fruit')

echom "Current index:" getcurpos(winid)[1]

# moving cursor down
win_execute(winid, "normal! j")

echom "Current index:" getcurpos(winid)[1]



Thanks! Oh, those lists look familiar:D I found out that line(“.”, windid) is also valid.

I forgot line accepts winid :)
